# How I can use Autonumber in new screen multiple users in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, autonumber

I have a custom screen in Acumatica with autonumber, but only one user can use at the same time. How can get screen multiuser?

In Sales Order/Payment and Applications I have a tab('COMPLEMENTOS'), in this tab you can add a new complement in other screen. This screen have a field, 'No. Complemento' is Autonumber, the autonumber is generated correctly but if two person are in the same screen at the same time, one of them is saved correctly but the other try to save with the same number that was already used and send an error 'Another Process has updated the CPSetup record. Your changes will be lost'. How I can work with two or more screens at the same time.

```
if (cache.GetStatus(row) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
{
   AutoNumberAttribute.SetLastNumberField<COPago.cOPagoCD>(cache, row, 
   typeof(CPSetup.returnLastDocRefNbr));
   if (row.RefNbrPago != null)
   {
      AutoNumberAttribute.SetPrefix<COPago.cOPagoCD>(cache, row, "REP");
   }
}
```

The actual error is  'Another Process has updated the CPSetup record. Your changes will be lost'
I would like to kwon how I can generate correctly autonumber with the same screen with two or more users at the same time.

Comment: So are two users modifying the same sales order?

Comment: Differents SO, the error is in additional Screen in SO

Comment: Can you please add the DAC and Numbering Attributes code to the question?

Comment: you should just use the AutoNumber attribute on your numbering field and the framework will do the auto numbering for you. Otherwise if you want to pick when to set the number you should use AutoNumberAttribute GetNextNumber to avoid the error you are getting. Note this will use up the number for each call and i don't think you can roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate next nunber probably you store it on a field on Numbering Sequence. We call it LastNumber.

When you update the LastNumber field (with next number) on Numbering Sequence you need to use an SQL transaction

```
using (PXTransactionScope ts = new 
PXTransactionScope())
{
    //Update LastNumber with next number
    // persist cache
    ts.Complete();
 }
```